# Objective C read-only int? What?

Tags: objective-c, int, readonly

I made an int to count how many successes one of my processes has. Outside my code, I declare:

`int successes = 0`.

Then within my loop, I have `successes++;`, at which point XCode complains that "variable is not assignable (missing _block type specifier)".

What is going on? Why can't I increment my int? I never declared it read-only...

Any help is much appreciated.

The code I used is:

```
_block int successes = 0;

for(CLLocation *location in locationOutputArray)
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             successes++;
             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", [topResult subThoroughfare],[topResult thoroughfare],[topResult locality], [topResult administrativeArea]];

             [addressOutputArray addObject:address];
             NSLog(@"%@",address);
         }

     }];

    [geocoder release];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `__block int successes = 0;`? You'd better show your code, because it's clear you're using blocks or something else you haven't told us.

Comment: just to make sure, is this a multi-threaded application?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your loop is inside a block (`^{...}` syntax). Blocks cannot alter variables outside of the block without that variable having a `__block` specifier.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much more sense. I didn't realize that syntax was called a block. How do I declare which block in front of it? `_block int successes = 0;` throws "Use of undeclared identifier '_block'".

Comment: Thank you so much! Will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: Thank you for the DOUBLE underscore comment; I couldn't figure out for the life of me what I was doing wrong, since the font used didn't separate the underscores.

Answer (score 11):

You tried accessing this `int` inside a block. Mark it as `__block` so it can be updated from within the block.

[Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6)